# Sharing a MongoDB connection with other js files

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Using Node.js/Express.js/Monk.js, I'm trying to share my MongoDB connection with other JS files.

In **apps.js**, I had declared:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/ta');
module.exports = db;
require('./libs/mylib');
```

(db works fine)

In **/lib/mylib.js** I had:

```
var db = require('db');
```

But I get the error: **Error: Cannot find module 'db'**

How can I make this **db** connection available through all my js libs ? (and is it the right approach?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In apps.js

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/ta');
module.exports = db;
```

In /lib/mylib.js

```
var db = require('../apps.js')
```

Though i would reccommend making a separate file called db.js and in that file export the connection ,that is more cleaner.

Comment: I knew that was an easy one ! ;) Thanks a lot Rana